# ¿Como clasificar numeros de una lista en Python?

Tags: python

tengo que resolver un problema en el que se clasifique la categoría de un conjunto de números de un diccionario de datos. Las categorías que estoy intentando encontrar son las siguientes: `1 Par` `2 pares` `1 tercia` `1 tercia y un par`.

Poniendo de ejemplo el siguiente diccionario `k=([('8', 2), ('9', 2), ('0', 1)])`, donde el numero entre comillas es un dígito, y el numero entero representa la cantidad de veces que se repite el número entre comillas. En este caso el resultado que me tendría que dar es: `2 pares` de números en mi lista.

Agrego una parte de mi código con el que ya intente realizar mi clasificación:

```
k=([('8', 2), ('9', 2), ('0', 1)])

terciaYPar = 0#variable que aumenta para verificar si existe una tercia y un par de números
dosPares = 0 #variable que aumenta para verificar si existen dos pares
for l, n in k:
    if(n == 2 ):
        dosPares += 1
        if(dosPares==1):
            print("Un par")
        elif(dosPares ==2):
            print("Se tienen dos pares ")
    elif(n == 3):
        print("se tiene una tercia")
        terciaYPar += 1 
        if(terciaYPar >=1):
            print("Hay una tercia y un par")
```

La salida que me da es la siguiente:

```
Un par
Se tienen dos pares
```

Pero solo quiero que me muestre la salida:

```
Se tienen dos pares
```

¿Que debo modificar de mi código para obtener el resultado que quiero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es contar los pares y tercias en la lista `k` usando compresión de listas antes de imprimir nada.

```
pares = len([x for x in k if x[1] == 2])
tercias = len([x for x in k if x[1] == 3])
```

Luego de contar, la impresión es simplemente:

```
pares, tercias = contar(test)
if tercias and pares:
    print(f"Se tienen {tercias} tercias y {pares} pares")
elif pares:
    print(f"Se tienen {pares} pares")
elif tercias:
    print(f"Se tiene {tercias} tercias")
```

**Demo**

```
tests = [[],
        [('8', 2), ('9', 2), ('0', 1)],
        [('0', 1)],
        [('2', 2), ('0', 1)],
        [('8', 2), ('9', 2), ('0', 3)],
        [('8', 3), ('9', 2), ('0', 1)],
    ]

for test in tests:
    print(test)
    pares, tercias = contar(test)
    if tercias and pares:
        print(f"Se tienen {tercias} tercias y {pares} pares")
    elif pares:
        print(f"Se tienen {pares} pares")
    elif tercias:
        print(f"Se tiene {tercias} tercias")
    print()
```

produce:

```
[]

[('8', 2), ('9', 2), ('0', 1)]
Se tienen 2 pares

[('0', 1)]

[('2', 2), ('0', 1)]
Se tienen 1 pares

[('8', 2), ('9', 2), ('0', 3)]
Se tienen 1 tercias y 2 pares

[('8', 3), ('9', 2), ('0', 1)]
Se tienen 1 tercias y 1 pares
```